# Is there anyway to use php-cgi with tomcat server?

Tags: php, c++, tomcat, nginx, cgi

I have a situation where a C/C++ application has a thread dedicated for nginx webserver and the thread and nginx server communicates via a specific port. This nginx server is configured to display the data (the data from the C/C++ application) on the webserver with the help of php-cgi. The port for php-cgi is different.

Is it possible to replace nginx server with tomcat server with minimal changes?

I came to know about php/java bridge while researching about it. I am not sure if that is the one I am looking for.

Please help.

Thanks

Edit: Any other cgi is okay as long as the data from the native C/C++ application is sent to webpages, but using tomcat server.